# Extract all Outlook emails' date, sender, recipient, subject to CSV

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com, archiving

**Intro**

I'd like to create some sort of archiving script, which would collect all Outlook (unicode) emails's date, sender (name+address), recipient(s) (name(s)+address(es)), subject and put them in a CSV file.

*(The extra super solution would be if it could extract the containing folders' name and possible categories as well - although it is not a must.
And as final step, I would like to make it portable, so others could use it without having Python.)*

*(I'm using Python 2.7 and Outlook 2013)*

**Code**

Here's what I have so far:

```
import win32com.client
import sys
import unicodecsv as csv

output_file = open('./outlook_farming_001.csv','wb')    
output_writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter = ";", encoding='latin2')

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. 
messages = inbox.Items

for i, message in enumerate(messages):              # enumerated the items
    try:

        sender = message.SenderName                 
        sender_address = message.sender.address         
        sent_to = message.To                    
        date = message.LastModificationTime         
        subject = message.subject                   

        output_writer.writerow([
            date, 
            sender, 
            sender_address,             
            sent_to,
            subject]) 

    except Exception as e:
        ()

output_file.close()
```

**The questions:**

1. How to make sure it extracts all the email? (When I run the script, it works, but it extracted only 1555 emails, although my Outlook Inbox sais, it contains 4785.)
2. How to make it work on all the Outlook folders? (It only deals with Inbox, but I would need all the other folders (sent, and other created ones))
3. How to get the recipients' email address? (I can only extract the screened names)

If you have any tip for any of the questions, that would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

For question 2:

```
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
```

"6" in the code refers to Inbox.

```
for folder in outlook.Folders: 
    print(folder.Name)
```

use the above for loop to look for all the folders in your mailbox.

For question 3:

To get sender email ID, you can use this piece of code:

```
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
sender_emailid =message.SenderEmailAddress
```

For question 1:
I dont have an answer. Sorry